# Does "a reply of sorts" mean "a sort of reply"?

Tags: grammar, word-meaning

​ 1. Does "a reply of sorts" equal "a sort/kind of reply?" Can we say "a reply of kinds" as well?
​ 2. The context below is an extract from the book *The Remains of the Day* by Kazuo Ishiguro. Is the text kind of complicated? Looks like the character is using a special style of talking.

> This was not the first time my employer had raised such a question; indeed, it 
>   seems to be something which genuinely troubles him. On this occasion, in fact, **a 
>   reply of sorts** did occur to me as I stood up there on the ladder; a reply to the effect that those of our profession, although we did not see a great deal of the country **in the sense of** touring the countryside and visiting picturesque sites, did actually "see" more of England than most, **placed as we were** in houses where the greatest ladies and gentlemen of the land gathered.
>   <sub>—The Remains of the Day, written by Kazuo Ishiguro.
>
>   (A longer excerpt of this extract can be found online [here](http://www.randomhouse.com/acmart/catalog/display.pperl?isbn=9780679731726&view=excerpt).)</sub>

​ 3. What does "in the sense of" mean? Can you rephrase it for me?
​ 4. Is there an inversion in "placed as we were"? I think is means as/since we were placed in...Is this inversion common? Are there any rules to understand them?

Comment: *in the sense of touring* → "the way a tourist might [see]*

Comment: I can count 8 questions in this question, and because I cannot answer all of them (and not to mention that it doesn't comply to our [guideline](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/767/should-we-mark-questions-containing-multiple-sub-questions-as-too-broad-until)), I couldn't provide you a good answer. However, **[of sorts](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/of-sorts)** means "used to describe something that is not a typical or good example of something".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. "a reply of sorts" means that although it could be classified (sorted) as a reply, it would have been an inferior one. Kind could not be substituted.
2. It is a more formal writing style, yes.
3. It means that although they did see the countryside, it wasn't in the same way that someone "touring the countryside and visiting picturesque sites. . ." would have. So in *a* (the literal) sense they did see the countryside, but in *the* (generally accepted) sense, they did not.
4. "having been placed" would be a possible substitute.